# Coded UI Tests fail using MsTest on Bamboo OnDemand

Tags: visual-studio-2013, mstest, coded-ui-tests, bamboo, ondemand

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 to create Coded UI Tests and would like to get them running with Bamboo On-Demand. I need them to be fully automated and controlled by bamboo not Microsoft Test Manager (I'm not using TFS anyway)

I have tried using the 'MS Test Runner' and have also tried calling MsTest.exe and vstest.command.exe directly. With each one I get this error "To run tests that interact with the desktop, you must set up the test agent to run as an interactive process."

I can remote desktop into the elastic image and successfully run the tests from the command prompt. It just seems to be an issue when the tests are ran from a build plan. Presumably because mstest doesn't run as an interactive process but I'm not sure what I can do about this.

Has anyone had any luck with this?

Comment: My eventual solution was simply to use Selenium instead